# Frattini subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z}_p)$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, frattini-subgroup

What is the Frattini subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb{Z}_p)$? If $\Phi$ denotes this Frattini subgroup and $\Gamma(p^r)$ denotes the kernel of the projection to $SL(2,\mathbb{Z}/p^r)$, then since $\Gamma(p)$ is pro-$p$, we have $\Phi\ge\Gamma(p^2)$.

However I believe $\Phi = \Gamma(p)$. Is this true? If possible I'd like to see an abstract group-theoretic argument, as well as a more geometric $p$-adic Lie-group style argument, if they exist.

Edit: Let's assume $p\ge 5$ for simplicity.

Comment: In this case, isn’t $\Phi$ be inverse image in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p$ of the Frattini subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: @Aphelli Yes, but is it obvious what this latter Frattini subgroup is?

Comment: @ThePhoenix That's very helpful! In second paper (by Vasiu), would you happen to know what "$c(G)$" is in the statement of the Main Theorem 1.3?